# iMac boot stuck after incomplete uninstall of Kaspersky Internet Security

Tags: imac, startup

Even though I perfectly knew that it wasn’t the right method to uninstall Kaspersky Internet Security for Mac, I dragged and dropped the app icon on the trash bin. Later, I switched it off.

The day after, the iMac couldn’t complete the boot: it was stuck at the apple logo with progress bar (half).
I tried to boot in safe mode, I reinstalled Big Sur: nothing.

I’m quite sure that during the boot some Kaspersky (kernel?) extension are required, and since macOs cannot find it it goes in loop.
So, the question is: how can I complete uninstall KIS from my Mac, considering that I cannot boot?

I tried to use the Terminal available in Recovery Mode, but it’s in read only mode, and I don’t know what to do…
I have a MacBook... Should I try to use my iMac HD as a target? And then do what?
Can anybody help me?

iMac late 2015 with Big Sur

Kaspersky Internet Security for Mac (from a Total Security bundle)

Comment: https://support.kaspersky.com/15587 [which I'm aware doesn't really help you now, but the golden rule for antivirus packages is *use the uninstaller*].

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot in Safe mode, the best way is :

1. reinstall Kaspersky Internet Security for Mac
2. use the link given by @Tetsujin to uninstall correctly the software.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot even boot in safe mode. Same result... I know, I should have used the uninstaller, but now I have ti find a way to fix this.

Comment: When you are in Recovery Mode in terminal, you can open a new terminal cmd+n and with the command `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`you can connect and dialog on the forum. Can you give the results of `diskutil list internal`?